# Javascript: Push Mouseflow session ID as a custom dimension to Google Analytics through Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I want to add the Mouseflow ID as a custom dimension in Analytics. I have my GTM correctly integrated, other tags and triggers work perfectly fine. I'm struggling with the following:

I *think* I need a custom variable containing javascript that returns the Mouseflow ID. I've used this link as a reference:

https://mouseflow.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/206505015-How-do-I-push-data-into-third-party-tools-

A custom Javscript variable in Google Tag Manager needs a function and return, so I can't use the code on the above website directly. Two of the things I've tried are:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   return mouseflow.getSessionId;
});
```

And:

```
function() {
    return mouseflow.getSessionId();
}
```

As you've guessed, I lack Javascript knowledge to implement the code correctly. I've been at it for hours now and thought it was the right time to ask this question here. Closest I've been is getting Object Object in the custom dimension in Analytics, which isn't actually close.

I test the variable by setting the variable as the label of an event, which I configure as a Mouseflow recording in GTM. Only the custom dimension with the variable remains (not set) or Object Object.

Thanks, and if I've missed anything or wasn't clear, please let me know.

Mick

Comment: Your first attempt is missing the parenthesis, so it returns the function object rather than executing the function that retrieves the session id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've currently set it up as following in Google Tag Manager:

A custom javascript variable containing the following:

```
function() { return mouseflow.getSessionId(); }
```

Added a window loaded trigger, made session-scoped dimension in my Google Analytics account. After that I added an event tag for my GA-code, which sets the chosen custom dimension slot with the variable added, using the window loaded trigger.

Worked for my case.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at this article:
https://mouseflow.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/206505595-Google-Analytics-Integration

Basically, it recommends doing something like this:

```
if (typeof ga != 'undefined' && typeof mouseflow != 'undefined') {
   ga('set', 'dimensionX', mouseflow.getSessionId());
   ga('send', 'event', 'Mouseflow', mouseflow.getSessionId(), {'nonInteraction': 1});
}
```

To use this, you'll need to create a custom dimension in Google Analytics first, and then add the correct dimension name to the code snippet above.

Comment: The OP asked specifically about integration via GTM, so that's not really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is that the mouseflow code is loaded at the page bottom. GTM is loaded at the start of the page. Try your second version for a custom js variable, but fire the GA tag only on page load (create a new pageview trigger and set trigger type to window loaded).

As an alternative, set the mouseflow ID in the page source code, push a variable to the datalayer and pick it up via a datalayer variable. Push to the datalayer after your mouseflow code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   dataLayer.push({"mouseflow_id": mouseflow.getSessionId});
});
```

then create a new variable of the type dataLayer, set the datalayer key to "mouseflow_id" and use that in your analytics tag.